# How does Scala parser combinators handle whitespace?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

---

I want to parse a document treating each line as a distinct token. A toy example might look something like this:

```
     August Pizza Sales
        2021-08-21

     22
     19
     53

     P.S. I <3
```

Lines might have arbitrary whitespace before and after the text. (My real case is more complicated, and might have different types of data sections, headers, etc. of arbitrary length.)

Here's a basic attempt:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

case class Document(
    title: String,
    date:  LocalDate,
    data:  Seq[Integer],

)

class LineParser extends RegexParsers {
    private val eol = sys.props("line.separator")

    def text:     Parser[String]       = ".*".r     ^^ { _.toString }
    def date:     Parser[LocalDate]    = ".*".r     ^^ { LocalDate.parse(_) }
    def blank:    Parser[String]       = "^\\s*$".r ^^ { _.toString }
    def datum:    Parser[Integer]      = "[0-9]+".r ^^ { _.toInt }
    def data:     Parser[Seq[Integer]] = repsep(datum, eol)
    def document: Parser[Document]     = text ~ date ~ blank ~ data ~ blank ~ text ^^ {
        case title ~ date ~ _ ~ data ~ _ ~ footer =>
            Document(title=title, date=date, data=data, footer=footer)
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get `Document(Pizza Sales,2021-08-21,List(23),19)`.

There are many things I don't understand here ...

### Tactical Questions

- What changes do I need to make to correctly parse the document?
- If I change my definition of `blank` to `"^\\s*$".r` (which is what should actually match a blank line, I think) then everything breaks. Why?

### Strategic Questions

- What's really going on with newlines here? The `text` parser does not match across newlines, so it seems they're being treated specially (i.e., even if I try to match `text` to the entire document, it only gets `Pizza Sales`.)
- What is the impact of setting `skipWhitespace`?
- What is the impact of setting `val whiteSpace = ...` (in combination with `skipWhitespace`)?
- [SUPER BONUS QUESTION] What the heck does `~>` mean?

### Philosophical Questions

Since I already know how to tokenize my input (i.e., split it on newlines), is `RegexParsers` (or Scala parser combinators in general) the right tool for this job?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `scala-parser-combinators`. They're slow and buggy and there isn't really any reason to use them instead of, say, atto (https://github.com/tpolecat/atto).

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt I'm definitely open to alternative parsers. All the links to atto documentation seem dead -- do you know where it is? Is there a reason for preferring atto to, say, FastParse or Parboiled?

Comment: It's here: https://tpolecat.github.io/atto/ .

Comment: Fastparse is not referentially transparent (why that matters is beyond the scope of this question). It heavily uses Scala 2 macros, so it's not compatible with Scala 3. And since it's not based on cats, you don't get all the standard operators and methods that cats offers. Therefore I would usually prefer atto, unless I know I really need fastparse's superior performance. I haven't used Parboiled, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: There's also a new project, cats-parse. I can't comment on its merits since I haven't used it yet. https://github.com/typelevel/cats-parse

Comment: I also have a library https://github.com/j-mie6/Parsley which I'm still actively maintaining and works in Scala 3. It has a lot of documentation and guides and I plan for this to expand further. It's just as fast as `fastparse` is has a more classic parser combinator design.